# Setting up Rcpp Armadillo in windows with Rstudio

Tags: windows, r, rcpp, armadillo

I am trying to set up RcppArmadillo in my windows system with Rstudio. I have successfully installed RcppArmadillo with the command

```
install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
```

in R console.

But when I try to compile a c++ code with RcppArmadillo dependency I get a error like

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/library/Rcpp/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c colrowStat.cpp -o colrowStat.o colrowStat.cpp:5:26: fatal error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. make: *** [colrowStat.o] Error 1 Warning message: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="sourceCpp_38187.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="colrowStat.o"' had status 2
```

But the header files are available in path_to_my_documents/R/win-libraries/3.0/RcppArmadillo/Include

I think the include path for compilation dose not have this path. I don't how to add this folder to the path. I greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.  There are many ways to do it, and we documented several of them.  What you do here is not one of them.

Try this instead and go from there:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> cppFunction("arma::mat op(arma::vec x) { return(x*x.t()); }", 
+              depends="RcppArmadillo")
R> op(1:2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    4
R>
```

This is one of the basic examples: take a vector, multiply it by its transpose and return the result outer product matrix.

What you ultimately want is a package, and for that you could do much worse than starting by `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is short on details, but if you are on a Windows machine and are using RStudio, then here is a fully reproducible example on how to use `RcppArmadillo` without using the `inline` package, which is not ideal except for very short functions.
As Dirk has pointed out, this advice is available elsewhere -- the Rcpp* ecosystem is bizarrely well-documented, but this might help a novice.

### 0. Preliminaries:

You should have the following installed:

1. [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)
2. R package [devtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html)
3. R package [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html)
4. R package [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppArmadillo/index.html)

### 1. C++ code:

The example is a simple one of computing the OLS estimator for a linear regression model. Here is what the C++ file, with one function (`fnLinRegRcpp`) that takes the design matrices as inputs and produces the OLS coefficient estimates and the model residuals as an Rcpp `List` looks like:

```
// LinearRegression.cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace arma;  // use the Armadillo library for matrix computations
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fnLinRegRcpp(vec vY, mat mX) {

  // compute the OLS estimator & model residuals
  vec vBeta =  solve(mX.t()*mX, mX.t()*vY);  
  vec vResid = vY - mX * vBeta;

  // construct the return object
  List ret;
  ret["beta"] = vBeta;
  ret["resid"] = vResid;

  return ret;
}

// END
```

Note the use of [Rcpp attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
```

to indicate library dependencies on the Armadillo library.

### 2. R code

Here is an example of the compilation of the C++ code using the `sourceCpp` function, together with an example of the use of the function, and a comparison of the output to the built-in `lm.fit` function.

```
# LinearRegression.R
library(devtools)
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)

Rcpp::sourceCpp("code/LinearRegression.cpp", 
                showOutput = TRUE, 
                rebuild = FALSE)

# generate some sample data
iK = 4
iN = 100
mX = cbind(1, matrix(rnorm(iK*iN), iN, iK))
vBeta0 = c(2, 3.5, 0.11, 6.33, 23)
vY = rnorm(iN, mean = mX %*% vBeta0)

# test the function
linReg1 = fnLinRegRcpp(vY, mX)
linReg1$beta  # coefficient estimates

# compare the results to the built-in lm.fit function
lm.fit(y = vY, x = mX)$coef  # coefficient estimates

# END
```

Comment: Your example is quite clear and good, and I run it well on my Rstudio with `sourceCpp` However, when I want to wrap it as a package, e.g., library(fnLinRegRcpp), following [Rarmadillo](https://www.amalag.com/armadillo/), something wrong happens like `<'vec' was not declared in this scope...>`. It seems that each `vec` or `mat` in your `LinearRegression.cpp` file should be something like `arma::vec` or `arma::mat`, while the `sourceCpp()` method doesn't need to be so troublesome.

Comment: Btw, I use  `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("fnLinRegRcpp")` to start, File-->New project-->Existing Directory, then add LinearRegression.cpp in the `src` directory. It finds it is working fine with `sourceCpp()` in library(RcppArmadillo) without any change of your cpp code, while it semms that something should be modified if we wrap it as a R package. Do I misunderstand?@tchakravarty

Comment: See also the examples in [How to build Rcpp packages within Rstudio using RcppArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486604) and [Moving from sourceCpp to a package with RcppArmadillo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020486), and I successfully wrap `rmvrnorm_arma2` and `cholcalcCpp` in R package, but failed on your `fnLinRegRcpp`  @tchakravarty